# Azure Machine Learning Studio vs. Workbench

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

What is the difference between [Azure Machine Learning Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-studio/) and [Azure Machine Learning Workbench](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-services/)?  What is the *intended* difference? And is it expected that Workbench is heading towards deprecation in favor of Studio?

I have gathered an assorted collection of differences:

- Studio has a hard limit of 10 GB total input of training data per module, whereas Workbench has a variable limit by price.
- Studio appears to have a more fully-featured GUI and user-friendly deployment tools, whereas Workbench appears to have more powerful / customizable deployment tools.
- etc.

However, I have also found several scattered references claiming that Studio is a renamed updated of Workbench, even though both services appear to still be offered.

For a fresh Data Scientist looking to adopt the Microsoft stack (potentially on an enterprise scale within the medium-term and for the long-term), which offering should I prefer?

Comment: If you haven't seen, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320679/difference-between-azure-ml-and-azure-ml-experimentation) may help give some differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be added that Azure Machine Learning Workbench [is deprecated since september 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/overview-what-happened-to-workbench) and has been replaced by the [Azure Machine Learning services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/), which was made generally available in december 2018. The core functionality is still intact, but some major changes to point out about the architecture are:

- A simplified Azure resources model
- New portal UI to manage your experiments and compute targets
- A new, more comprehensive Python SDK
- A new expanded Azure CLI extension for machine learning

Comment: HI All, I understand azure ml studio have limitations to process not more than 10 GB of data but we can process more than 10 GB using python from Data Lake store files or using HIVE External table. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Azure Machine Learning Workbench is a preview downloadable application. It provides a UI for many of the Azure Machine Learning CLI commands, particularly around experimentation submission for Python based jobs to DSVM or HDI. The Azure Machine Learning CLI is made up of many key functions, such as job submisison, and creation of real time web services. The workbench installer provided a way to install everything required to participate in the preview.

Azure Machine Learning Studio is an older product, and provides a drag and drop interface for creating simply machine learning processes. It has limitations about the size of the data that can be handled (about 10gigs of processing). Learning and customer requests have based on this service have contributed to the design of the new Azure Machine Learning CLI mentioned above.

Comment: Workbench is deprecated and replaced by Machine Learning Services, [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604773/azure-machine-learning-studio-vs-workbench/53476451#answer-53476451)