# No Experimentation Account found in your Azure Subscriptions in Azure Machine Learning Workbench

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I created one Experiment and hosted as web service in Azure ML Stdio

https://studio.azureml.net/

However, I have installed Azure Machine Learning Workbench and logging into same account. It says:

**No Experimentation Account found in your Azure Subscriptions
You can create one in the Microsoft Azure Management Portal.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that an experiment in Azure ML Studio is different than what Azure ML Workbench is looking for. Like the message says try creating an experiment in the Azure Portal, like the one below and it should find that and let you continue.

Hope that helps, but let me know if you have more questions.

[image]

Comment: Got your point. Thank you..By the way, where we will use AZURE ML Studio and Azure Workbench..I am little confused which one I should use and what purpose.why microsoft has two ways to play Machine learning?

Comment: Hopefully, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320679/difference-between-azure-ml-and-azure-ml-experimentation/49321419#49321419) I did a while back on the differences should help. In my opinion, on which to use what service, I'd say that Azure ML Studio is great for prototyping and learning while Azure ML Workbench is more for production level models, especially if you want to go more of the Python route. I will say that Workbench is still in beta, so be wary of some bugs with it. Hope that helps!